# Weird Java String comparison

Tags: java, string-comparison

I'm having a minor issue with Java String comparisons.

I've written a class which takes in a String and parses it into a custom tree type. I've written a toString class which then converts this tree back to a String again. As part of my unit tests I'm just checking that the String generated by the toString method is the same as the String that was parsed in the first place.

Here is my simple test with a few printouts so that we can see whats going on.

```
final String exp1 = "(a|b)";
final String exp2 = "((a|b)|c)";
final Node tree1 = Reader.parseExpression2(exp1);
final Node tree2 = Reader.parseExpression2(exp2);
final String t1 = tree1.toString();
final String t2 = tree2.toString();

System.out.println(":" + exp1 + ":" + t1 + ":");
System.out.println(":" + exp2 + ":" + t2 + ":");

System.out.println(exp1.compareToIgnoreCase(t1));
System.out.println(exp2.compareToIgnoreCase(t2));

System.out.println(exp1.equals(t1));
System.out.println(exp2.equals(t2));
```

Has the following output; (NB ":" - are used as delineators so I can ensure theres no extra whitespace)

```
:(a|b):(a|b):
:((a|b)|c):((a|b)|c):
-1
-1
false
false
```

Based on manually comparing the strings exp1 and exp2 to t1 and t2 respectively, they are exactly the same. But for some reason Java is insisting they are different.

This isn't the obvious mistake of using `==` instead of `.equals()` but I'm stumped as to why two seemingly identical strings are different. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Try comparing them with a diff tool, that will show you which characters are different. Or is that what you meant by "manually comparing"?

Comment: In order to help, we need to see the parsing and toString code.

Comment: @DonRoby Surely the problem is with comparing the two strings that are seemingly identical rather than with how they are generated. I'll happily post code as it may help find the solution faster, but it's a bit of a mess at the moment.

Comment: @NateC-K I meant just a visual comparison. What diff tools would you recommend? (I'm a linux/mac user so terminal commands would be great)

Comment: @ChrisSalij: try piping the output to hexdump (`java whatever... | hexdump -C`) and look closely at the output.

Comment: Show the imports for `Node` and `Reader`.  `java.io.Reader` does not have a parseExpression2 method.

Comment: If strings seem to be identical but aren't, the problem is in how they are generated.

Comment: @DwB The reader class is a custom class. Not `java.io.Reader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does one of your strings have a null character within it?  These might not be visible when you use `System.out.println(...)`.

For example, consider this class:

```
public class StringComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "a|b";
        String t = "a|b\0";
        System.out.println(":" + s + ":" + t + ":");
        System.out.println(s.equals(t));
    }
}
```

When I ran this on Linux it gave me the following output:

```
:a|b:a|b:
false
```

(I also ran it on Windows, but the null character showed up as a space.)

Comment: This seems to be the cause. I know about null characters, but didn't think of checking for them. I just get the length of exp1 (5) and the length of t1 (6), so I assume I'm adding a null character at the end  somehow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it certainly *looks* okay. What I would do would be to iterate over both strings using `charAt` to compare every single character with the equivalent in the other string. This will, at a minimum, hopefully tell you the offending character.

Also output everything else you can find out about both strings, such as the length.

It could be that one of the characters, while looking the same, may be some other Unicode doppelganger :-)

You may also want to capture that output and do a detailed binary dump on it, such as loading it up into gvim and using the hex conversion tool, or executing `od -xcb` (if available) on the captured output. There may be an obvious difference when you get down to the binary examination level.

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions

- Copy each output and paste in Notepad (or any similar editor), then
  copy them again and do something like this

  System.out.println("(a|b)".compareToIgnoreCase("(a|b)"));
- Print out the integer representation of each character. If it is a weird unicode, the int representation will be different.
- Also what version of JDK are you using?